# unresolved external symbol due to CString

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a prject where the main process is a DLL and it is being used the UI project.

When I declare a variable in the DLL project as below

```
CString NewMethod;
```

I get the above error unresolved external symbol in the UI project.

NewPNCUI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall WBFilter::~WBFilter(void)" (??1WBFilter@@QAE@XZ)

Here WBFilter is a completely separate class and unrelated.

How do I solve this?

Many thanks.

Best Regards

Chitnan

Comment: Check your 'Use of MFC' in the project configuration settings.

Comment: Ensure you link the DLL with ATL and/or MFC as required.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I have linked the DLL with MFC and if I uncomment my declaration, the project builds perfectly fine.

Comment: Are you trying to export the variable called NewMethod from the dll?

Comment: @doctorlove No. I just declared it and tried to build the project. And I got the above error.

Comment: Are you claiming if you remove CString NewMethod; the link error goes away?

Comment: @doctorlove Yes, it does go away.